# Strange Null Pointer Exception in my tests passes one but fails other

Tags: java, android, mockito

Trying to use test driven development and ran into a NPE that I can't resolve and obviously because of that one of my tests fail.

In a method to fetch items I pass in a limit int and then instantiate a callback.

this is exactly where it falis the listener returns null I think.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

---

Test class

package com.techyourchance.testdrivendevelopment.example11;

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class FetchCartItemsUseCaseTest {

        public static final int LIMIT = 10;
        public static final int PRICE = 5;
        public static final String ID = "id";
        public static final String TITLE = "title";
        public static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
        FetchCartItemsUseCase SUT;

        @Mock
        FetchCartItemsUseCase.Listener mListnerMock1;
        FetchCartItemsUseCase.Listener mListnerMock2;
        @Mock
        GetCartItemsHttpEndpoint mGetCartItemsHttpEndpointMock;

        @Captor
        ArgumentCaptor<List<CartItem>> mAcListCartItem;

        @Before
        public void setup() throws Exception {

            SUT = new FetchCartItemsUseCase(mGetCartItemsHttpEndpointMock);

            success();

        }

        private void success() {
            doAnswer(new Answer() {
                @Override
                public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                    Callback callback = (Callback) args[1];
                    callback.onGetCartItemsSucceeded(getCartItemSchemes());
                    return null;
                }
            }).when(mGetCartItemsHttpEndpointMock).getCartItems(anyInt(), any(Callback.class));
        }

        private List<CartItemSchema> getCartItemSchemes() {
            List<CartItemSchema> schemas = new ArrayList<>();
            schemas.add(new CartItemSchema(ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, PRICE));
            return schemas;


        }

        @Test
        public void fetchCartItems_correctLimitPassedToEndPoint() throws Exception {

            ArgumentCaptor<Integer> acInt = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);

            SUT.fetchCartItemsAndNotify(LIMIT);

            verify(mGetCartItemsHttpEndpointMock).getCartItems(acInt.capture(), any(GetCartItemsHttpEndpoint.Callback.class));
            assertThat(acInt.getValue(), is(LIMIT));

        }

        @Test
        public void fetchCartItems_success_observersNotifiedWithCorrectData() throws Exception {

            SUT.registerListener(mListnerMock1);
            SUT.registerListener(mListnerMock2);
            SUT.fetchCartItemsAndNotify(LIMIT);
            verify(mListnerMock1).onCartItemsFetched(mAcListCartItem.capture());
            verify(mListnerMock2).onCartItemsFetched(mAcListCartItem.capture());

            List<List<CartItem>> captures = mAcListCartItem.getAllValues();
            List<CartItem> capture1 = captures.get(0);
            List<CartItem> capture2 = captures.get(1);

            assertThat(capture1, is(getCartItems()));
            assertThat(capture2, is(getCartItems()));


        }

        private List<CartItem> getCartItems() {
            List<CartItem> cartItems = new ArrayList<>();
            cartItems.add(new CartItem(ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, PRICE));
            return cartItems;

        }
        //correct limit passed to the endpoint

        //success - all observers notified with correct data

        //success - unsubscribed observers not notified

        //general error - observers notified of failure

        //network error - observers notified of failure


    }


    public class FetchCartItemsUseCase {


        private final List<Listener> mListeners = new ArrayList<>();
        private final GetCartItemsHttpEndpoint mGetCartItemsHttpEndpoint;

        public FetchCartItemsUseCase(GetCartItemsHttpEndpoint mGetCartItemsHttpEndpoint) {
            this.mGetCartItemsHttpEndpoint = mGetCartItemsHttpEndpoint;
        }

        public void fetchCartItemsAndNotify(int limit) {

            mGetCartItemsHttpEndpoint.getCartItems(limit, new GetCartItemsHttpEndpoint.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onGetCartItemsSucceeded(List<CartItemSchema> cartItems) {
                    for(Listener listener : mListeners) {
                        listener.onCartItemsFetched(cartItemsFromSchemas(cartItems));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onGetCartItemsFailed(GetCartItemsHttpEndpoint.FailReason failReason) {

                }
            }) ;


        }

        private List<CartItem> cartItemsFromSchemas(List<CartItemSchema> cartItemSchemas) {
            List<CartItem> cartItems = new ArrayList<>();
            for(CartItemSchema schema : cartItemSchemas) {
                cartItems.add(new CartItem(schema.getId(), schema.getTitle(),
                        schema.getDescription(), schema.getPrice()));
            }

            return cartItems;
        }

        public void registerListener(Listener listener) {

            mListeners.add(listener);
        }

        public interface Listener {
            Void onCartItemsFetched(List<CartItem> capture);

        }
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Sea.png
 really lost would appreciate any help
```

---

```
public class FetchReputationUseCaseSync {

    private GetReputationHttpEndpointSync mGetReputationHttpEndpointSync;

    public FetchReputationUseCaseSync(GetReputationHttpEndpointSync getReputationHttpEndpointSync) {
        this.mGetReputationHttpEndpointSync = getReputationHttpEndpointSync;
    }

    public UseCaseResult fetchReputation() {
        GetReputationHttpEndpointSync.EndpointResult result;

        try{
            result = mGetReputationHttpEndpointSync.getReputationSync();

        }catch (NetworkErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return UseCaseResult.FAILURE;
        }

        switch(result.getStatus()) {
            case SUCCESS:
                return UseCaseResult.SUCCESS;

            case GENERAL_ERROR:
                return UseCaseResult.FAILURE;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("invalid status: " + result);
        }
    }

    public enum UseCaseResult{
        SUCCESS, FAILURE
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line in your code is line 26 :-)?

Comment: @fjc Seems to be inside the for loop of onGetCartItemsSucceeded (the stack call names that function).

More importantly, OP, can we see your tests?  Specifically from the call stack, the answer function and line 63.

Comment: ok I,ll add them now

Comment: Youre missing an @Mock annotation for mListnerMock2.

Comment: Can you try adding @Mock above FetchCartItemsUseCase.Listener mListnerMock2 ?

Comment: You are a diamond Geezer, my typo!!! Passes now. Great.